# How inject git revision into Nix derivation?

Tags: git, nix

There are libraries such as gitrev, which allows to compile in git revision into executable file, but in case of using `nix-build http://../master` git meta data are missing in the source tree.

How to reference derivation revision in such situation to have it at least inside shellHook?

Comment: Depends on your expressions. `(builtins.fetchGit args).rev` is one way. `self.rev` for flakes. If all you have is a path, like a variable containing the value of `(builtins.fetchGit args).outPath` or something, there's no way. Probably best not to set it as a drv attribute, or you'll cause more rebuilds than necessary; especially in repos with multiple derivations with distinct sources.

Comment: http urls will be fetched and turned into paths at the cli level. I don't expect the contents of `http://.../master` to retain this info. I know on github those archives don't.

Comment: @RobertHensing, if default.nix file inside git repo - there is nothing to fetch, right? So fetchGit is not usable?

Comment: If you have a local checkout, you can set `url = ./.;`, where `./.` is the path to your clone's root.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar for `system.nixos.tags`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject git revision of the current Nix flake into derivation by using `self.rev`.

`flake.nix`:

```hs
{
  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs";
  outputs = { self, nixpkgs }:
    let
      system = "x86_64-linux";
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
    in
    {
      devShells.${system}.default = pkgs.mkShell {
        shellHook = ''
          echo "Nix flake revision is ${self.rev or self.dirtyRev or "dirty"}"
          echo "nixpkgs revision is ${nixpkgs.rev}"
        '';
      };
    };
  nixConfig.bash-prompt-suffix = "[devshell] ";
}
```

```
$ git init
$ git add flake.nix
$ git commit -m initial
$ nix develop
Nix flake revision is 32074a3b6583d7677f3aeb3679f75c190ab62c78
nixpkgs revision is bd1cde45c77891214131cbbea5b1203e485a9d51
```

Revisions of other flake inputs can be used as well. [Starting from Nix v2.17 `dirtyRev` and `dirtyShortRev` are also provided](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/5385) (thus you can remove the `or "dirty"` part) in case the git working directory is in a modified state.

---

As of 2023, Nix flake is the de-facto standard of developing, building and packaging software projects.